# Force PDF download with PHP - file corrupt on Windows

Tags: php, pdf, header

I have PHP code forcing the download of a PDF. It works on a Mac but not from a Windows machine. I guess it's maybe something to do with the linux server reading the code and creating the file that a mac can read but not windows?

```
$filename = str_replace(' ', '%20', $_GET['brochure']);
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
readfile('http://siteurl.com/media/download/'.$filename);
die();
```

Any suggestions on how to get this PDF download Windows friendly?

The error message is

> Could not open 'filename..' because it is either not a supported file
>   type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an
>   email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

Comment: What if you point your browser directly to `http://siteurl.com/media/download/'.$filename`?

Comment: Try saving the file and opening it in notepad (or a similar simple file editor) to see if there are any errors at the top of the file.

Comment: @ilanco Yeah no problem there. But the url must not be visible to the downloader (clients request)

Comment: @BartS. opened the file and it actually contains the rendered html page that the link above code is on

Comment: That means you're not reading the correct file. Are you sure you're using `readfile()` correctly? Shouldn't it point to a PDF on the local file system (something like `readfile('/var/www/files/media/' . $filename):`? Right now you're reading the file from another webhost.

Comment: @iamjonesy Is the file you are trying to send stored on a different server than the one where your PHP script is hosted?

Comment: Nope the file is on the same server. Just retrieving it using the domain name

Comment: If the file is hosted on the same server, you should use the local path to it (otherwise you're just wasting bandwidth). More importantly: are you doing any `echo's` or `?> <html stuff><?php` before you do the `readfile()` bit?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your browser is caching an older version of the file. Try adding these headers to your code:

```
header("Cache-Control:  maxage=1");
header("Pragma: public");
```

Another option:

Save the file in a temporary directory and use the following code to send it to the client:

```
$file = readfile('/tmp/'.$filename);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: thanks but still getting error message - I've added it to my question

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the filename needs .pdf on the end so that Windows can interpret it properly. Try downloading the file renaming it with a .pdf on the end and then trying to open it.

Comment: Looking at the properties in windows it 'type of file'is set to Adobe Acrobat Document (.pdf)

Comment: "Could not open 'filename..' " & "opened the file and it actually contains the rendered html page ". To me it looks like there is something wrong with the link to download the file. Can you post the actual text of the link after it hase been expanded.